# Dapper - like operator using DynamicParameters

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

This works:

```
var list = conn.Query<int>(
  "select Id from Person where Id in @ids", 
  new { ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } }
);
```

This throws "No mapping exists from object type System.Int32[] to a known managed provider native type.":

```
DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters(
  new { ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } }
);
var list2 = conn.Query<int>(
  "select Id from Person where Id in @ids", 
  parameters
);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Simply a use-case that hasn't been considered. You might want to log it on the issues list for dapper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just fixed this issue in the latest dapper (grab from hg), the code used to diverge around the DynamicParameters value extraction. Now the code being run is the same.